# Did not Find class "io.socket.client.IO". Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, cloudboost

Did not Find class "io.socket.client.IO".
I am using CloudBoost to authenticating my app but it gives this error I also add socketio.jar but it does not work.

The Exception is :

```
02-14 16:42:02.785 2811-2811/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat, PID: 2811
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/socket/client/IO;
at io.cloudboost.util.CloudSocket.init(CloudSocket.java:25)
at io.cloudboost.CloudApp.init(CloudApp.java:108)
at a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"io.socket.client.IO" on path: DexPathList[[dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-
25.1.1_3476f8c094ba03aae53add4760e990ddec2a2b1a-classes.dex", dex file    
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-socketio_55ab5d4d7f6337ed54c1ab8bc5b667256bd56ac4-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file
 "/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file
 "/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file     
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file
 "/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file
 "/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-25.1.1_e1e64186be867c4e764a6b04c42d8a3ac6917563-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-25.1.1_9d5402b063c129172b571e1b091c3c7f91a0b6f3-classes.dex", dex file
 "/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-25.1.1_cf5448b367965e3b03bddbb928c4244c70bed8b4-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-25.1.1_8c935c8d4923de5580ac08513c2635fa847dc638-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-utils-25.1.1_2c64802c8c9f25e06b072c5de05821326c0c505d-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-25.1.1_f6796b3ddc5852014c6565312344bdd02f4eace6-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-25.1.1_8f5d4b9a60d3718ee5a402bc05bb5ed83326a555-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-25.1.1_0eb0dc0336dbab3f12ddad6a928d681368f78a1f-classes.dex", dex file 
"/data/data/a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-25.1.1_c1efe34864e5c1396c7093dab651c32158418e15-clas
```

My MainActivity Code id-:

```
package a52.puri.fbkunal.com.chat;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import io.cloudboost.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CloudApp.init("Appid", "Key");

}
}
```

I would be thankful if anyone can help me.

Comment: I use  compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }